# Shell Script error: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

Here is my code aiming to diff .in and .out file in batches. Both .in and .out files are in same directory and sorted by name. So, two files needed to test should be adjacent in directory. But when I want to use `outFile=${arr[$(i++)]}` to get the .out file, it shows `i++: command not found`. What's the error in my script?

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=$PATH
arr=($dir/*)

for((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++));do
        inFile=${arr[$i]}
        outFile=${arr[$(i++)]}
        if diff $inFile $outFile > /dev/null; then
                echo Same
        else
                echo $inFile
        fi
done
```

Comment: `PATH` is (nearly always) not a single directory, but a colon-separated list of directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(( i++ ))`. That's two (not one) parenthesis.

- `$( )` runs shell commands.
- `$(( ))` evaluates arithmetic expressions.

Also:

- Your script uses `bash` features (arrays), it's best to use `#!/bin/bash` to avoid confusion.
- I'm not sure what you expect `dir=$PATH` to do? `$PATH` is a special environment variable that is used for the lookup of commands. This is probably not what you want, if I understand the intent of the script correctly.
- `i++` will increment the value *after* being used; so here `inFile` and `outFile` are in fact the same! You probably want to use `++i` (which will modify the variable and *then* use it), or just `i + 1` (which will not modify the variable).

Comment: `i++` also means you're modifying `i` in two places; just use `$(( i + 1))` for `outFile`, and use `i+=2` in the for loop to iterate over two files at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The stuff in brackets is already evaluated in arithmetic context, like within `$(( ... ))`. So you can do:

```
for (( i=0; i < ${#arr[@]}; ));do
    inFile=${arr[i++]}
    outFile=${arr[i++]}
```

References:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays

> The *subscript* is treated as an arithmetic expression ...

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.